# how to hold a increment number bill in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hye im doing cashier app..Can someone tell me how to hold an increment number for a purchased list?Cashier have a list of item of customer then the customer go and get some item and want to hold.So when hold, the cashier can scan item of others customer first.Example,i hold number bill 1.So the next bill is 2.When im paid for bill 2 so it will be bill 3 right?so now im calling back for paid the bill 1.When im paid for bill one the bill become counting back to bill 2.But bill 2 i already paid. How to hold the increment number of bill ?

this is MainActivity.class

```
Hold.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String invoice = txt_referName.getText().toString() + txt_referNum.getText().toString();

            insertHoldListMaster(invoice);
            myDb.deleteAllItemPurchased();
            displayItemPurchased(MainActivity.this);

        }
    });
```

AdapterHoldList.class

public class AdapterHoldList extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList<Product_Item> itemsList;
//SQLite
DatabaseHelper myDb;
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

public AdapterHoldList(Context ctx, ArrayList<Product_Item> itemsList){
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
}

public class HoldListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView invoice, timestamp, totalPrice;
    public Button btnReadyPay, btnDel;

    public HoldListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        invoice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_holdReferBill);
        timestamp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtHold_DateTimeBill);
        totalPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtHold_TotalPriceBill);
        btnReadyPay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_holdReadyPay);
        btnDel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_holdDel);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public HoldListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_hold_list, viewGroup, false);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
    return new HoldListViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final HoldListViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    final Product_Item item = itemsList.get(position);
    final Double itemAmt = item.getItemTotalPrice();
    final String invoice = item.getInvoice();

    String strItemPrice = format.format(itemAmt);

    holder.invoice.setText(item.getInvoice());
    holder.timestamp.setText(item.getTimestamp());
    holder.totalPrice.setText(strItemPrice);

    holder.btnReadyPay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean success = AddToList(invoice);
            if (success) {
                MainActivity.displayItemPurchased(ctx);
                ((Activity)ctx).finish();
            }
        }
    });

    holder.btnDel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            deleteHoldList(holder.getAdapterPosition(), invoice);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemsList.size();
}

private void deleteHoldList(int position, String invoice){
    myDb.deleteHoldListDt(invoice);
    myDb.deleteHoldList(invoice);
    itemsList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    HoldListActivity.displayHoldList(ctx);
    myDb.close();
}

private boolean AddToList(String invoice){
    myDb.deleteAllItemPurchased();
    Cursor cursorHold = myDb.getAllHoldListDtByInvoice(invoice);
    while (cursorHold.moveToNext()) {
        String itemId = cursorHold.getString(1);
        String itemDescription = cursorHold.getString(2);
        Double itemUnitPrice = cursorHold.getDouble(3);
        int itemQty = cursorHold.getInt(4);
        Double itemTotalPrice = cursorHold.getDouble(5);

        myDb.insertItemPurchased(itemId,itemDescription,itemUnitPrice,itemQty,itemTotalPrice);
    }
    myDb.close();
    return true;
}
```

}

PaymentMethod.class

```
btn_paymentPayNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (txtCard.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                PaymentPayCredit();
            }else{
                PaymentPayCash();
            }
        }
    });

public void PaymentPayCash(){
    Double paid = Double.valueOf(txtPaid.getText().toString());
    Double change = Double.valueOf(txtChange.getText().toString());
    if (paid > 0 && change >= 0) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = (new AlertDialog.Builder(PaymentMethod.this));
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Double totalPay = Double.valueOf(txt_AmtDue.getText().toString());
                Double totalDisc = Double.valueOf(txtDetailDiscount.getText().toString());
                Double UserPaid = Double.valueOf(txtPaid.getText().toString());
                Double BalancePaid = Double.valueOf(txtChange.getText().toString());

                myDb.insertSuccessPayMaster(prefix + suffix,"","","",totalPay,totalDisc, UserPaid, BalancePaid);
                insertSuccessPayDt();

                myDb.deleteAllItemPurchased();
                MainActivity.displayItemPurchased(PaymentMethod.this);

                //exit cash sales
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PaymentMethod.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
                progressDialog.show();

                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            Toast.makeText(PaymentMethod.this,"Payment Succesfull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(PaymentMethod.this,PrintSuccessPayCash.class);
                            intent.putExtra("InvoiceNo", prefix + suffix );
                            startActivity(intent);
                            suffix++;
                            myDb.insertPrefix(prefix, suffix,"invoice");
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", null);
        alertDialog.setMessage("Confirm to Pay & Print " + prefix + suffix + " ?");
        alertDialog.setTitle("Confirmation");
        alertDialog.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(PaymentMethod.this,"Please pay enough amount",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

btw im doing increment on suffix++..How to solve it?if u can help my code isokay, just help me with the idea of hold increment bill number function..Thanks in advance.

Comment: nobody knows what is your calculation formula. What exactly is a problem for you to do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the TextWatcher to fire an event when the user inputs data into an textfield. Then you can make your calculations.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements TextWatcher {

    //some other code...

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         //TODO: Calculations...  
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //Nothing to do here...
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        //Nothing to do here...
    }
}
```

Comment: ok this is what i need to know thanks.